# Windows 11 de-activated and refuses to activate again

Tags: windows-11, windows-activation

I have Windows 11. It was activated, I bought the license on Microsoft Store and it was connected to my Windows user account. A couple of days ago I noticed "Activate Windows. Go to Settings to activate Windows" message on my desktop. In Settings > System > Activated state" it says "Not active". When I expand the section it says:

> Something prevented us from communicating with our activation severs. Wait a few minutes and then try again. Error code: 0x803F700F

I pressed the Troubleshoot button but it did not help. How do I re-activate windows?

PS. I did not do any hardware changes, just updated motherboard bios.

Comment: I have window 11. It was activated, I bought the license on Microsoft Store and it was connected to my Windows user account.     ...  Contact Microsoft Store Support and ask them to activate

Comment: BIOS upgrade could have been the culprit if it was key provided by amnufacturer, but if you bought it in Microsoft Store then that seems unrelated. Is the option to reactivate in settings not available?

Comment: I suppose anything might happen but BIOS (UEFI) Updates on my machines have not caused registration issues. I am not disagreeing with you , merely saying I have not seen this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to re-activate windows. What I did was:

1. Rebooted my PC.
2. Settings > System > Activate State > Troubleshoot
3. Select option "I changed my hardware" (even though I did not).
4. It showed me the list of PC's to activate. Strangely, it had two identical items for my PC.
5. When I selected the first one and clicked "Activate" button, it showed me the error "Unable to activate Windows. We can't activate your copy of Windows as the digital license for this device has already been used to reactivate Windows."
6. Instead I went through steps 2-4 again and selected the second item, clicked "Activate" and it worked.